# Replace Characters in .txt file with Another Character from a Defined List

Tags: c#

I am creating a simple WPF Program that will read and write .txt files for a simple character switcher/scrambler.

I want to be able to create a list of Definitions in a file for every character to replace it with another character that will be used to switch the characters when its ran.

for example:

```html
a = x
b = r
c = e
d = u
```

and so on

So essentially I to want be able to select a .txt file and run a C# script when my button is pressed that will replace all characters in the .txt file with the predefined definition of it from the list above and save that changed version as a .txt file. I also want to be able to select the changed .txt file and revert it to the original characters if possible when another button is pressed.

I already have the WPF program set up with the buttons and File directory stuff, I need help with the C# implementation of actually making this idea work as I can't find any resources online that are covering what I am describing. Any guidance on where to look and or what to do next would be appreciated.

Comment: And what are you asking us to do? Are you stuck with reading the "A=x" file and creating a map or are you stuck with transforming the "file you want to 'encrypt'"?

Comment: The latter, I am unfamiliar with as you say "encrypting" a file. Things such as replacing character's with another. Whether or not I need another file for holding the data such as "a = x" is over my head, just looking for a simple and practical approach for doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to read your mapping file and create a map. I pondered a few ways of doing this but easiest is probably to use a dictionary

```
var config = File.ReadAllLines(...);

 //declare these at class level probably, I only put here to make my code work and show the definition 
var scramble = new Dictionary<char, char>();
var unscramble = new Dictionary<char, char>();

foreach(var line in config){
  var a = line.First();
  var b = line.Last();

  scramble[a] = b;
  unscramble[b] = a;

}
```

Then you have to process your file. It would be more memory efficient to read char by char using a StreamReader than to read to as a string and convert to char (needs twice the memory) but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. Here I take the quick and dirty method of reading the file and then turning it into a char array immediately, but it briefly requires twice the memory as the file is big:

```
var chars = File.ReadAllText(...).ToArray();

for(int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
  if(scramble.ContainsKey(chars[i]))
    chars[i] = scramble[chars[i]];
```

Writing the chars array to disk as the newly scrambled file is an exercise for you. Unscrambling is a similar pattern

Comment: This was very useful, Thank You!

Comment: No problem! ps; `if(scramble.TryGetValue(chars[i], out char scrambled) chars[i] = scrambled;` might also save a few nanonseconds over ContainsKey.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1) let's get the text into a format that we can read through.

```cs
var FileText = File.ReadAllText(filename.txt).ToArray();
```

Step 2) we need to decide how to find the characters in the string. A very basic way to achieve this is going to be to loop through the string that we have searching for our characters.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < FileText.length; i++)
{
    switch (FileText[i])
    {
        case 'a':
            FileText[i] = 'x';
            break;
        ... // Fill out cases for each substitution
        default:
        // This character is something we don't care about, so keep looping
        continue;
    }
}
```

There are very likely more efficient solutions, but this will at least get the job done while not being too complex.

Edit:
As per Caius' comment, the assignment to a string indexer doesn't work. It needed to be a character array. I tested the change, and it seems to work now. The downside of this solution is it is not configurable, though.

Comment: The switch block makes no sense. Use `string.Replace` for every character from the map.

Comment: You cannot assign to a string indexer